# online_presence no longer working

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying the following FQL query to get the `online_presence` of my friends:

```
SELECT
  uid, name, online_presence
FROM
  user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

But it's returning these kind of elements for every single of my friends:

```
{
  "uid": 150323242,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "online_presence": null
}
```

This started happening yesterday, did I miss any announcement on the FQL API no longer working?

If I did, is there a way to get this via the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/263442327069657, you should add yourself as someone who can repro and follow it.